# Yolov7 custom trained model error in flutter project

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, object-detection, yolo, tflite

I am getting the following error when I am running my tflite model in the flutter app for object detection using yolov7

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy to a TensorFlowLite tensor (serving_default_images) with 2076672 bytes from a Java Buffer with 14976 bytes.
```

I found that we need to change some variables in `TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java` file but i am unable to find this file in the flutter project.